# Find $x$ if $AD=CB$. Justify geometrically.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

[image]

I need help with this geometry question. Find $x$ if $AD=CB$. Justify geometrically.

I tried plotting it on GeoGebra and found that $x=30\unicode{176}$ but I don't know how to prove it, I also tried with a system of linear equations but it has no solution:

$\begin{cases}70\unicode{176}+x_2+x_3=180\unicode{176}\\[5pt]
70\unicode{176}+x_1+40\unicode{176}+x_2=180\unicode{176}\\[5pt]
40\unicode{176}+x_1+\left(180\unicode{176}-x_3\right)=180\unicode{176}\end{cases}$

I also tried drawing the heights of the $2$ triangles to get right triangles but I end up with more unknowns.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Geogebra]

Comment: AD, BC  lengths are not equal in the given sketches.

Comment: @Narasimham, I'm reminded of a description I once heard. Something along the lines of: "Geometry is the science of drawing correct conclusions from terribly incorrect drawings."

Comment: @OP, it's not a big issue but the points are mislabelled. I believe this has confused many people. It is best if you fix it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick $D'$ on $AC$ such that $CD'=CB$. Then triangle $CBD'$ is isosceles with a top angle of $40^\circ$. The remaining two angles are $70^\circ$.

Now take a look at points $D,D'$. By hypothesis $AD=CD'$ so $D,D'$ are symmetric with respect to the midpoint of $AC$.

Moreover, $BD, BD'$ are also symmetric with respect to the bisector of the angle $\angle ABC$ since $\angle ABD = \angle D'BC = 70^\circ$.

This is only possible if the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles and $AB=BC$. This gives $\angle B = 100^\circ$ and $\angle DBC = 30^\circ$.

---

To conclude that the triangle is isosceles do the following

- consider a triangle $AD'B'$, translating the triangle $DCB$ until $AD'$ and $DC$ overlap.
- then $\angle ABD'= \angle AB'D'$, showing that $A,D',B,B'$ are on the same circle
- by construction $BB'||AC$, thus  $A,D',B,B'$ are the vertices of an isosceles trapeze. The non-parallel edges and diagonals are equal, implying that the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles also.

Comment: @CalvinLin I think the intended meaning was: $BD$ and $BD'$ are symmetric wrt the bisector of angle $ABC$. Then the solution seems to work, but the conclusion that $ABC$ is isosceles if far from trivial and, in my opinion, requires some explanation.

Comment: @timon92: I added some explanation. I wouldn't say that the conclusion is "far from trivial". In any case where both symmetry with respect to a midpoint and the corresponding angle bisector is present, the only option is to have complete symmetry.

Comment: @CalvinLin: I meant that the lines $BD, BD'$ are symmetric with respect to the angle bisector.

Comment: @BeniBogosel Thanks for more detailed explanation. Could you please clarify why $AA'=CC'$?

Comment: @timon92: Sorry... I don't know what I was thinking. The previous argument had an error. I updated it with, hopefully, a correct one.

Comment: Now it looks correct. Nice proof!

Comment: Ah, you completed the proof in a much different manner than I expected, and I agree that it is correct. $\quad$ I had a short one-line argument assuming that you meant the points $D, D'$ were symmetric about the angle bisector, which was how I thought you were arguing. $\quad$ With this proof, the limiting case of $ x = 0 ^\circ$ also results in $A = D'$ so $ ABB'$ is just a triangle, and we can draw no conclusions about the side lengths.

Answer (score 3):

If you're familiar with sine rule, then apply it to $BDC$ and $BDA$ to get

$$\frac{BC}{\sin 40^\circ + x }  = \frac{BD}{\sin 40^\circ}, \frac{AD}{\sin 70^\circ} = \frac{BD}{\sin 70^\circ - x}.$$

Since $BC = AD$, hence

$$ \frac{\sin 40^\circ + x } {\sin 40^\circ} = \frac{BC}{BD} = \frac{AD}{BD} = \frac {\sin 70^\circ} {\sin 70^\circ - x}.$$

Thus (with a bit of work), $x = 0^\circ, 30^\circ$.

Note: It is arguable if $ x = 0^\circ$ is a valid solution, as one may argue that the diagram indicates $  0^\circ < x < 110^\circ $. However, it bears to bote that for $x = 0^\circ$, we do have $BC = AD$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be the circumcenter of $ABD$. Since $\angle ABD = 70^\circ$, we have $\angle XDA = 90^\circ - \angle ABD = 20^\circ$.

Let $Y$ be so that $XDCY$ is a parallelogram. Note that $ACYX$ is an isosceles trapezoid because $AC\parallel XY$ and $AX=DX=CY$. Also note that $\angle YCD =\angle XDA = 20^\circ$, hence
$$\angle BCY = \angle BCD - \angle YCD = 40^\circ - 20^\circ = 20^\circ.$$
We are given $BC=AD$. Hence by SAS the triangles $XDA$, $YCB$ are congruent. In particular $YB=XA=XB$.

Since $ACYX$ is an isosceles trapezoid, the segments $AC$, $YX$ have the same perpendicular bisector, call it $\ell$. Since $BX=BY$, the point $B$ lies on $\ell$. Hence the whole figure is symmetric. In particular $\angle CAB = \angle BCA = 40^\circ$, hence $\angle ABC = 100^\circ$ and $\angle DBC = 30^\circ$.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution!!

Comment: Ahhhh... K, adding that in would be helpful the symmetry. I was looking into how we can prove $AB = BC$ to get symmetry, but you were using symmetry to conclude that $AB = BC$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ AD=BC=1;$$

Mark angles by angle chasing ( angle sum 180 and external angle sum equals sum of two internal angles )

$$AP+PD= h \cot (70 -x)+h \cot (40 + x)=1,~h / BC=  1. \sin (40) $$

Solving numerically we directly get

$$ x=30, h\approx 0.643788;$$

This can be also put down by inspection or by careful trial & error.

[image]

EDIT1;

Next, the numerical solution  $DBC'=x=180$ deg (continuation of BD) also supplies a second solution. The second possible construction satisfying same geometry is sketched below superimposed with the first one.

It is noted in conclusion that

$$ BA = BC= BC'=AD.$$

[image]